# Can i use CLI without Elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir, command-line-interface, release

I create simple CLI app on Elixir. Can i release my app and use it on the other PC without Elixir and Erlang? I read a few materials on the CLI and didn't find any release instructions.

Comment: Did you try Distillery https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/home.html

Comment: Just build `escript` https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/advanced/escripts/

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin escripts still require ERTS

Comment: @Hauleth I never tried it, but I was under impression that producing release out of the project including `escript` would contain ERTS.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin no, it will not, at least not by default. You can do some magic to enable such behaviour though, but it will not be that straightforward.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin In my simple CLI I use escript, but i don't understand how use it in other PC without Erlang

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (e.g. using Distillery) but it's not guaranteed that the distributed app will work on all other systems (even within the same OS). So, it's OK if you want to do this for one or two friends but it's a bad idea to publicly distribute your software in this manner.